# "Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement" Getting error while adding framework manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when I try to add framework manually it shows me error like " **Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement**" and when I checked it in details it looks like following:

**ld: framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I tried with adding architectures like arm7, amr7s, amr64 and arm64e in build setting.

Already clean derived data and clean + build and restart Xcode.

Answer (score 10):

This happens if you have enabled automatic icloud upload for desktop/documents. To fix this issue, navigate to the pods folder where you have created the ios project, inside pods folder find GoogleAppMeasurement > Frameworks >. Then, right click on on the GoogleAppMeasurement.framework and click "Download". This will download the file from icloud and should solve the problem

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm this.

1. Copy your whole project somewhere outside iCloud.
2. Delete the (empty) folder GoogleAppMeasurement inside the Pods folder
3. rerun "pod install" in Terminal

Now it should work.

Comment: Actually icloud backup was corrupting all my projects within the Documents folder. I had to turn it off. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the Answer for this question, but someone might land here as I did.
I had the Pod `Firebase/Analytics` in the project and had to replace it with `Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport` as should avoid using Tracking to conform ATT. Anyway, as i updated the Podfile as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios#disable-IDFA-collection i got the above error.

**To solve the issue**, I had to update "other linker flags" in the targets Build Settings from "GoogleAppMeasurement" to "GoogleAppMeasurementWithoutAdIdSupport" of course for all in the App.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was getting mentally ready to spend the day on this...

Answer (score 4):

I received this error when iCloud on my MacBook had cleaned up the GoogleAppMeasurement in the pod file to increase storage space. It cleaned up most of the pod files over the next couple of days as well as the actual swift files. Still working on a fix for this - temporary fixes are usable iCloud and loose important documents also stored there, or copy and paste code into a new Xcode project.

Very frustrating!!

Answer (score 3):

Do "pod update" and that will fix since most likely iCloud messed up some things .

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment. Also had the problem that iCloud removed the files from the system. After deactivating the files from Desktop and Documents are removed from the local mac, but they can then be downloaded or "dragged" to any local folder from the iCloud Drive folder in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I realized that the folder location of my project is connected to iCloud. I fixed the issue by clicking the "download from cloud" and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I had to update "other linker flags" in the targets Build Settings from "GoogleAppMeasurementWithoutAdIdSupport" to "GoogleAppMeasurement"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30644952)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend restart Xcode and the computer itself. That worked for me.